# Form resulting in blank post with no ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Rails and working on creating a generic "facebook" type of app as practice with users and posts associated with each user. However, I'm currently having an issue where I think the form that I am using to create the posts is also being rendered out as a blank post with no post ID where I display all of the posts in a section below. I think that this post is being shown even before it is being saved to the database.

Here is my code in my view:

```
<div class="newpostcontainer">
      <div class="newposttext">
          <%= form_for([@user, @user.posts.build]) do |f| %>
          <%= f.text_area :post, size: "69x1" %>
      </div>
      <div class="newpostsubmitbutton">
        <%= f.submit %>
      </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>

     <% @user.posts.reverse_each do |p| %>     
    <div class="postedcontainer">
      <div class="minipostpic">
        <%= image_tag @user.photo.url, width: 32, height: 32 %> 
      </div>
      <div class="nameofposter"><%= @user.name %></div>
      <div class="dateofpost"><%= p.created_at%></div>
      <div class="postcontent"><%= p.id%></div> <br>
      <div class="postcontent"><%= p.post%></div> <br>
      <div class="likecommentdelete">
        <%= link_to "Delete", [p.user, p], method: :delete %> | Like | Comment
      </div>
    </div>
    <%end%>
  </div>
```

Here is my controller:

```
def index
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @posts = @user.posts.all
end

def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @post = @user.posts.create!(post_params)

    redirect_to user_path(@user)

end

def show
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @post = @user.posts.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to user_path(@user)
end

def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @post = @user.posts.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy
    if @post.destroy
        redirect_to user_path(@user)
    else
        redirect_to users_path
    end
end


private

def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit!
end


end
```

And here is my model:

```
  class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :user
        has_many :comments
        validates_presence_of :post

    end
```

I'm pretty sure the issue has something to do with my form to create the new post because when I remove it or comment it out, the extra blank post with no post ID goes away.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to permit the field values to be posted:

i.e.,

```
params.require(:post).permit!
```

should be

`params.require(:post).permit(:name, :post)`

then only it will POST I think.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because of rails 4 strong parameter feature. You need to whitelist your active models parameters. For more details refer to [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters).

In your case you need to do something like this:

```
params.require(:post).permit(:post)
```

where the ":post" inside require is your model and the other one is your permitted field that is your textarea.

Answer (score 0):

Several issues -

**Form**

```
<%= form_for([@user, @user.posts.build]) do |f| %>
```

Why are you building an associative object? `@user.posts.build` will not persist your data, and will cause all sorts of non-conventional issues I would highly recommending building the `posts` associative object in your controller's `new` action before using in the view, so you can do this:

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
def new
     @user = current_user
     @user.posts.build
end

<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
```

---

**Association**

You're trying to edit the `post` attribute with this statement:

```
<%= f.text_area :post, size: "69x1" %>
```

This won't work in any circumstance, as `:post` is an association, not an object. Rails only allows you to change / add *`attributes`* to specific objects, which means you'll be better doing something like this:

```
<%= f.fields_for :posts do |p| %>
    <%= p.text_area :title %>
    <%= p.text_area :body %>
<% end %>
```

---

**Strong Params**

You're currently permitting all your params? You'll be better doing this:

```
def post_params
    params.require(:user).permit(posts_attributes: [:title, :body])
end
```

---

Use Posts Controller

A better way will be to just use the `posts_controller`, like this:

```
#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
def new
    @post = Post.new
end

def create 
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.save
end

#app/views/posts/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
     <%= f.text_field :title %>
     <%= f.text_field :body %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks Rich - that's very helpful!! I went with your method using the posts controller. However, now I am getting an error in my form "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty". This error points to the <%= form_for @post do |f| %> line. The argument error is "ArgumentError in Users#show". How do I fix this?

Comment: You'll need to create @post = Post.new in your users controller show action

Comment: Thanks! I actually did do that, however, was having issues because I get an error that reads: undefined method `posts_path' for #<#<Class:0x000001012f68e8>:0x000001012f5df8>. So, I tried to add a redirect in the user controller show action to:redirect_to user_path(@user), however, I then get another error saying that: This webpage has a redirect loop